# HTML Formatter - with this specific format

Tags: html, formatter

I know there're a lot of HTML formatter. I've tried tons but none fit my requirement. Please suggest if u met something that can:

1) Convert

```
    <div><%=request.getAttribute("NAV")%><div>
    BB<span>CC<input type="text" value="123"></span></div></div>
```

Into

```
    <div><%=request.getAttribute("NAV")%>
        <div>BB
            <span>CC
                <input type="text" value="123">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2) Preserve all symbols

```
    (/>'/ wont be converted to /&gt;')
    (space wont be converted to &nbsp)
    (&nbsp wont be converted to space)
```

3) Wont make

```
    <input type="text" value="123">
```

Into

```
    <input type="text"
    value="123">
```

What the tools only need to do is to new line every new `<xxx` and add indent for each `<xxx` & `/xxx>` nest.

Comment: I use VS2010 and it seems it's doing the above. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

Comment: Yes, you do. You should post the whole page. Otherwise some formatters won't work.

Comment: I'm downloading VS 2010 Express... quite big for my formatter ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML formatters have a habit of stripping php/ruby code and template tags, so make sure that before validating, that your HTML is 100% HTML.

I know a HTML formatter that will

- Convert
- Preserve all symbols
- Not make unnecessary line breaks

http://dirtymarkup.com

Review the HTML code for abnormalities before replacing your existing HTML with it.

Comment: it's not suit me. Coz cannot support if mix with scriptlet <%%>. As u said, must be pure HTML. Currently i'm using my own HTML formatter using jQuery. It's like MS Visual Web Developer output with slightly tweak. Of couse mine formatter only support a few regular TAG and miss most of the rare JSTL tag.

Comment: I don't think one of those exist on the internet. I've looked myself for them periodically over the years.